# Async response - can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: node.js, express

I am new to Node.js programming. I am having a big trouble as I keep getting same error in the following code. I can not understand what is the problem there.

> Can't set headers after they are sent.

```
 var mongoose = require('mongoose');

 module.exports = function(req, res) {
    var User = require('../../Schema/User');
    User.count({ $and: [{ "username": req.body.username }, { "password": req.body.password }] },
        function(err, count) {
            console.log(count);
            res.json(count);
        });
};
```

Comment: can you show some more of your code. I know what is causing the issue, wont be able to help you until and unless you provide some more of your code.

Comment: ` var express = require('express');
`var route = express.Router();route.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
    require('../../Models/User/loginUser')(req, res);
    next();
});
`module.exports = route; ` this is from where i am calling above code

Comment: which is the file that you posted above?

Comment: Actually i am trying to use MVC above file is my model file for user login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `next()` in your route code essentially turning your login snippet into middleware and passing it down. You are getting this error because in your login code you are outputting with `res.json` and then still calling the next step with `next`. l.

Your issue is just that headers must come before any output. Whether you write or pass the data on in your middleware is up to you as long as you are aware of subsequent possible headers/writes.

But you may want to reconsider your setup - in general auth middleware would be used to verify that a user is logged on - perhaps checking a session cookie. If the user is ok then you can fetch (if needed) user data based on the cookie info (i.e. the _id) or redirect the user to a login page.

What you have here is the `login` route which doesnt really need middleware. Simply check if user is valid and either set a session cookie or tell them it's a no go.

Passport makes things easier. Check out this [post](http://mherman.org/blog/2015/01/31/local-authentication-with-passport-and-express-4/#.V8M7Y2WMDdQ). The underlying principle is the same I outlined above, it just makes it easier to get going.

Comment: yes i am just trying to use this as login middleware. Is there any better way to do that ? I still want to send response from a  asynchronous function .

Comment: In general you would not output from middleware. The idea is to do something and pass it down to your final function which then ends/outputs. You can tie things to the request from your middleware `req.foo = 'bar` and then access that in subsequent code. It will be much more manageable.

Comment: I was trying to use **MVC** design pattern with express routing via  this approach . something like [this example](http://timstermatic.github.io/blog/2013/08/17/a-simple-mvc-framework-with-node-and-express/)

Comment: Your issue isn't an MVC one , simply just knowing that headers need to come before any output. Your headers are probably coming in the next function where my guess is you render a template.  I've updated my post with additional info to help you get going.